# Custom proof environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

How to define another proof environment, say, for the "Proof of lemma"? Also, how to make it without the qed box? (I need one with qed box, and another one without qed box.)

I'm using amsbook document class with amsthm package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you're using `amsthm`, you don't need another proof environment.  the features you want are already built in.

to get a heading "Proof of lemma", use

```
\begin{proof}[Proof of lemma]
```

to omit the box, just before `\end{proof}` insert

```
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}
```

(this does not persist after the proof ends.)

both features are described in the manual: `texdoc amsthm`

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser: uppercase letters coming from your keyboard :-).